# Javascript loop through array inside an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am trying to DRY up this code, specifically instead of manually typing out the elems options in the if/else statement I want to loop through (or increment the numbers). I've tried using all kinds of loops but cant get it to work inside the .change() event.

```
var radioSelect = $("input[type='radio']");
var elems = ["q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q6"];

radioSelect.change(function () {

    // grab the name and value selected radio
    // set localstorage
    var linkName = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).val();
    localStorage.setItem(linkName, value);

    // I am trying to loop/increment both through the elements
    // and also through the #response[x] divs.
    if (link_name === elems[1]) 
    {
        $("#response1").html(localStorage.getItem(linkName));
    } 
    else if (link_name === elems[2]) 
    {
        $("#response2").html(localStorage.getItem(linkName));
    }  
    else if (link_name === elems[3]) {
        $("#response3").html(localStorage.getItem(linkName));
    }
});
```

Basic HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="Yes">
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="No">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `if/else` by `for` loop as below:

```
var radioSelect = $("input[type='radio']");
var elems = ["q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q6"];

radioSelect.change(function () {

    // grab the name and value selected radio
    // set localstorage
    var linkName = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).val();
    localStorage.setItem(linkName, value);

    // I am trying to loop/increment both through the elements
    // and also through the #response[x] divs.
    for( var i=1; i<=elem.length; i++){
        if (link_name === elems[i]){
            $("#response"+i).html(localStorage.getItem(linkName));
            break;
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elems.forEach(function(elem){
  if (linkName === elem) {
   $("#response" + elem.substring(1)).html(localStorage.getItem(linkName));
  }
})
```